# How to get the indentation of a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, indentation

Is there a way to get the indentation of a JSON file? How can I extract from the JSON file `j` its indentation (4)?

```
import json
j = json.dumps({'x': 1, 'y': 2}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

My aim is to compare two JSON files but if the indentation of the two files is different the output will notice that some lines with the same content but with different number of spaces are different.

Comment: Given arbitrary JSON data, there's no reason to believe that indentation is uniform without scanning *all* the whitespace.

Comment: If the JSON file only contains `{}` which indentation would you expect?

Comment: Fair point @Wombatz, I would say 0 but I don't think is correct...

Comment: Why compare the representation of the data, when you could compare *the parsed data itself* (which doesn't include *any* indentation at all)?

Comment: That's probably what I need to do and what I tried to avoid so far @CharlesDuffy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look for the first line that starts with a whitespace character and count the number of whitespaces till the first non-whitespace character (easily done with regular expressions). But why do you need to know?

Comment: there is no guarantee that there will be any whitespace(s) or that indentation is consistent.

Comment: it is potentially brittle for sure (and I also wonder why they need that info in the first place, hence my asking), but when specifying `indent=<positive integer>`, there indeed is a guarantee.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand the question. You are correct if they want to get the indentation for a file that they created

Comment: I edited the question with the reason why I need the indentation

Comment: "Why do you need to know?" - In my case, I'm adding a new key to an existing file. It was serialized with `indent=N` to make it more human-readable, and I'd like to maintain that structure when I write my addition to disk

Answer (score 2):

since you added your aim is to compare two different json files, it seems to me the far more robust approach is to compare their data representation, i.e. `json.load(file_1) == json.load(file_2)`

Comment: That's not good enough for me... I'm using this class https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html to get the difference line by line of the two files

Comment: is your data deeply nested? If not, I'd suggest using the `set` data structure to figure out differences. Difflib isn't always going to be robust enough either.

Comment: Unfortunately my data is really nested (at least 4 levels); I'm probably gonna double check the file with your first answer (reg. expr.) :)